# MonthCalendar width on different (platforms), correction: themes (XP vs Aero theme) 

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, controls

Apparently the .NET monthcalendar renders differently on different platforms. A calendar on Vista is wider than a XP calendar.

I want to make the calendar fit nicely and precise on all platforms.
Is there a way to do this, without having to measure and hard code the different widths ?

..............

Edit/Correction :
The calendar seems to render differently based on the theme you select :

[image]

How to compensate for that ?

Comment: Are you resolution on both the platforms same?

Comment: The calendar renders differently according to the platform, regardless of screen resolution ...

Answer (score 3):

That is the expected behavior. If you don't want to be effected by themes, disable theming completely (i.e. don't execute the command `Application.EnableVisualStyles();`). Otherwise different themes will always yield different looks for the controls (as they are meant to do). If you want to fit the controls in at all times, use a more fluent layout making use of anchors and docking.

Comment: But not calling Application.EnableVisualStyles will cause other problems, for example ListView not rendering all views correctly ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874295/why-does-my-listview-keep-drawing-in-largeicon-view

Comment: Then if you both want the visual styles enabled and controls fit, the other option is to use a fluent layout. Also if ListView is giving you problems, set its appearance to flat.

Comment: can you explain please what you mean with a fluent layout ?

Comment: I mean making use of anchoring and docking. Here are some good reading stuff on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770094/resizing-a-single-control-in-winforms and http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/winforms/part7.shtml

Comment: Thanks Teoman, I know about anchoring and docking though. The form is MDI child form that consists of a left panel (containing the container and having a fixed size), 2 vertical scrollbars, and a tablelayoutpanel in the middle which fills up the free space (fully anchored). Therefore I'll always have to know the size of the calendar, don't I ?? I'm also finding it hard to accept that this is expected behavior. If there's a Width property, I expect the width of the control to be the same... regardless of the theme you have selected ... how on earth could you otherwise design a nice layout ...?

Comment: Yes if you want to have exact fit, you'll have to get the size and do adjustments as required if you don't dock the control to left. Maybe you can spare some space for this sort of minor moves. And yes, theming has always been a problem with winforms and width adjustments.

Comment: Thanks Teoman, yes that's exactly the problem... If there was a property like 'RenderWidth' or something, i could simply adjust the size of the first column. Unfortunately i can't find such a property or method ... :-) thanks though ..

Comment: You're welcome and don't be so pessimistic. Think of web developers trying to adjust the size of things for ie6/ie7/ie8/ff3/ff4/chrome/.... :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found a workaround:

It seems that the dimensions of the `MonthCalendar` control are updated correctly when it is shown (like in a form) in runtime.

Use, e.g., the form's `Shown` event to know when the dimensions are updated.

You can also set the form's `AutoSize` property to `true` and `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowAndShrink` to make the form automatically fit the `MonthCalendar` control.

Update:

For more details try this example:

Put a MonthCalendar control on a form like this:

[image: Form with MonthCalender control]

In the **form's** Shown event add this:

```
public static int CalenderWidth = 0, CalenderHeight = 0;

private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CalenderWidth = monthCalendar1.Width;
    CalenderHeight = monthCalendar1.Height;

    MessageBox.Show("MonthControl width: " + CalenderWidth.ToString() +
                    ", height: " + CalenderHeight.ToString());
}
```

When the program is run you will see a messagebox showing the right dimensions.
The Width and Height are also put into two variables you can use anywhere in your program (in a quick and dirty way, I know ;-)
Of course you can omit the messagebox if you don't want it.

To check it is really working try changing the Region settings in Windows: Change the Format to e.g. Danish. Run the program again and you will see the Width has gotten smaller because a Danish MonthCalender control is smaller.

Regarding the `AutoSize`and `AutoSizeMode` properties they can be used to make the size of the form adapt to the size of the MonthCalender control. Do this:
Change the two properties in the **form** into this:

[image: Form's properties (Visual Studio)]

Now run the program and you will see that the size of the form changes automatically depending of the size of the MonthCalender control:

[image: Result]

That's it! (remember to switch your Region format setting back to the original one)

Comment: Do you have some code that you could share to illustrate the use of the `Shown` event and the `AutoSize` techniques that you mentioned?

Comment: I have now added an example ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found this :

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/34174436/vista-monthcalendar-control.aspx

> Welcome to Microsoft Manage Newsgroup again, I'm Zhi-Xin Ye, it's my
>   pleasure to work with you on this issue.
>
> The MonthCalendar control  is rendered by the OS and hence is rendered
>   different between XP and Vista. You can use the
>   Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major property to determine the OS version,
>   and call MontheCalendar.GetPreferredSize() method to retrieve the prefered
>   size on Vista, so that you can programmatically change the size of the form
>   to make it fit for the MonthCalendar. Meanwhile, turn the AutoSize property
>   of the form to true so that the form will resize on Vista, and make sure
>   the Dock property of  the MonthCalendar is set to Dock.None.
>
> Sample code for your information:
>
> private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>   {
>
> if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
>   {
>   this.Size = this.monthCalendar1.GetPreferredSize(new
>   Size());
>   }
>   }
>
> Please try my suggestion and let me know whether it makes sense to you. If
>   you have any questions or concerns, please do not hesitate to let me know.
>
> Best Regards,
>   Zhi-Xin Ye
>   Microsoft Managed Newsgroup Support Team

There seems to be a method specially designed for this issue :

```
this.monthCalendar1.GetPreferredSize(new Size());
```

However, I tested this method on multiple machines, and will give you always a preferred width of 178 px, regardless of theme or OS. (For as far as I tested). !?

So, being fed up, I'm just gonna give the calendar a width of 178, and plan to buy a commercial control or something in the like.
Thanks for all the help...

Answer (score 0):

My app is using Application.EnableVisualStyles();
I disabled Calendar visual styles in CreateHandle() method:

```
public class MonthCalendarBuffered : MonthCalendar
{
    protected override void CreateHandle()
    {
       Application.VisualStyleState = VisualStyleState.NoneEnabled;     
       // disables Application.UseVisualStyles
       base.CreateHandle();
       // restore setting
       Application.VisualStyleState = VisualStyleState.ClientAndNonClientAreasEnabled;
    }

 ...
```

Check Calendar control source at:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/MonthCalendar.cs

Comment: Can you expend on your answer. It seems to work in the visual studio Designer. But when I launch my application the style seems to revert back to default.